# Overwrite response status of endpoint in expressjs

Tags: javascript, express

I managed to redirect root `'/'` to `'/users'` but `'/users'` endpoint status overwrites the root endpoint status.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/users');
});
    
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(data.filter(user => user.isActive === true));
});
```

How is it possible to check whether `'/users'` endpoint is accessed through redirect or not and then set `res.status` appropriately?

Comment: Not sure if the http headers such as referrer will tell you something. Otherwise, you can ass yourself something to the header maybe, or  just add a query string value to the URL

Comment: Why are you trying to set a different status if the request comes after a redirect?  That's not how things are supposed to work in http.  A GET request for a URL/resource should return the same contents and status whether it's right after a redirect or not. If you want to make a different request from a redirect, then either redirect to a different URL or add a query string parameter, either of which you can detect on your server and then send an appropriate response for that request because it's a different request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want root api http status to be send in response of /users api but below hack can be applied to recognise if request are received from root api.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/users?redirect=true');
});
    
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  const redirect = req.query.redirect;
  if (redirect) {
    res.status(301).json(data.filter(user => user.isActive === true));
  } else {
    res.status(200).json(data.filter(user => user.isActive === true));
  }
});
```